# Best way to retrieve facebook profile images using MVC5 OWIN

Tags: facebook, asp.net-mvc-5, google-apps, owin

I am using OWIN in mvc5 to authenticate users, but I want to show their profile pictures as well. I have searched on strackoverflow and found the following way to get it done.

This is for facebook & Google plus :

[https://plus.google.com/s2/photos/profile/[USERID]?sz=100](https://plus.google.com/s2/photos/profile/%5BUSERID%5D?sz=100)

[http://graph.facebook.com/[USERID]/picture?type=square](http://graph.facebook.com/%5BUSERID%5D/picture?type=square)

Is this the best way to retrieve the images? Should we store images onto our server and load locally or we call these links every time someone logs in ? I need a proper approach, e.g. If we store them locally then they won't be updated if user changes their profile picture on facebook but if we load them every time from facebook then it takes some loading time to do a 302 redirect to actual image url.

Answer (score 2):

If you're just trying to display the images on a website, I would just store the link your given from Facebook/Google when someone logs in to your site in a local database and use the URL as the image src on the website. Facebook and Google will be storing these images on fast CDNs, you might as well take advantage.

This will off load the image storage and the need to serve up images from your own site, reducing load and storage requirements.

Then every time a user logs into your site retrieve their profile pic urls again and store them to make sure they are up to date.